# Vapor - How to assign multiple domains to routes?

Tags: swift, vapor

I would like to host multiple domains with one Vapor server. In the documentation, I do not see where we can assign domains to routes? Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation, this seems the intended method:

```
drop.group(host: "vapor.codes") { vapor in
vapor.get { request in
    // only responds to requests to vapor.codes
}
```

See here: https://docs.vapor.codes/2.0/routing/group/#host

Comment: Didn’t this do what you asked?